# django-filter and django custom pagination with ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination, django-filter

I implemented a modelviewset with django-filter and django default pagination comnbined. Its working fine when I use either django-filter or django pagination. But when they are used simultaneously then I am getting duplicate results in response.

So whats the correct way to use pagination in django-filter with CBV?

```
class TableMetaView(ModelViewSet):
    """
    This will be used to create new tables.
    You require to add the table fields in json request and also the job request associated with that
    table.
    If you want to create new table then pass CREATE NEW TABLE
    In response you will get the table list along with the job request for each tables
    """

    serializer_class = TableMetaSerializer
    queryset = TableMeta.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    filterset_fields = [
        "schema_name",
        "type",
        "status",
        "grouping__name",
        "dataset__name",
    ]
    ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
    ordering = ["-modified_on"]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    permission_classes = [
        UserHasDatasetChangeAccess & IsTableEditable,
    ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if getattr(self, "swagger_fake_view", False):
            # queryset just for schema generation metadata
            return TableMeta.objects.none()
        return TableMeta.objects.filter(
            dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""))
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I managed to do some changes and code is now running fine with django-filters and pagination.

## custom_pagination.py

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from constance import config
from rest_framework.pagination import (  # noqa
    CursorPagination,
    LimitOffsetPagination,
    PageNumberPagination,
)
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"
    max_page_size = 50

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(
            OrderedDict(
                {
                    "next": self.get_next_link(),
                    "previous": self.get_previous_link(),
                    "results": data,
                }
            )
        )
```

## views.py

```
class TableMetaView(ModelViewSet):
    """
    This will be used to create new tables.
    You require to add the table fields in json request and also the job request associated with that
    table.
    If you want to create new table then pass CREATE NEW TABLE
    In response you will get the table list along with the job request for each tables
    """

    serializer_class = TableMetaSerializer
    queryset = TableMeta.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    filterset_class = TableFilter
    ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
    ordering = ["-modified_on"]
    pagination_class = MyPagination

    permission_classes = [
        UserHasDatasetChangeAccess & IsTableEditable,
    ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if getattr(self, "swagger_fake_view", False):
            # queryset just for schema generation metadata
            return TableMeta.objects.none()
        return TableMeta.objects.filter(
            dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""))
        )

    def list(self, request: Request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        filtered_qs = self.filterset_class(request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset()).qs
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset=filtered_qs)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

## custom_filter.py

```
class TableFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = TableMeta
        fields = {
            "name": ["exact", "icontains"],
            "schema_name": ["exact"],
            "type": ["exact"],
            "status": ["exact"],
            "grouping__name": ["exact"],
            "dataset__name": ["exact"],
        }
```

Also you need to set default ordering

## models.py

```
class TableMeta(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-modified_on'] # list of fields here
```

After this django-filters and pagination are working fine in ModelViewSet.